# Trying out PyQt4, not able to crawl multiple webpages

Tags: python

I'm trying to alter [this code](http://blog.motane.lu/2009/07/07/downloading-a-pages-content-with-python-and-webkit/) to crawl multiple URLs at once and capture specific javascript tags thrown.  Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import signal
import urllib
import re
import csv
import time

from optparse import OptionParser
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

class Crawler( QWebPage ):
    def __init__(self, url, file):
        QWebPage.__init__( self )
        self._url = url
        #print(url)
        self._file = file
        #print(file)

    def crawl( self ):
        signal.signal( signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL )
        self.connect( self, SIGNAL( 'loadFinished(bool)' ), self._finished_loading )
        #print(self._url)
        self.mainFrame().load( QUrl( self._url ) )

    def _finished_loading( self, result ):
        print(self._url)
        file = open( self._file, 'a' )
        s = QtCore.QString('aJavascriptKeyword')
        val = (self.mainFrame().toHtml().indexOf(s) >= 0)
        #print val
        file.write( self._url + '^' + str(val) )
        #print( self._url + '^' + str(val) )
        file.close()
        sys.exit( 0 )

def main():
    app = QApplication( sys.argv )

    urls = open(r'urls.txt','r')
    #output=open(r'C:\Users\me\output.txt','w')
    for url in urls:
        #print(url)
        crawler = Crawler( url, "output.txt" )
        crawler.crawl()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this case, urls.txt is just a text file with one url per line.  When I run this with a file containing 1 url it works perfectly, but when I run with > 1 url, only the final url is passed to finished_loading().  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
for url in urls:
    ...
    crawler = Crawler( url, "output.txt" )
    crawler.crawl()
```

Completes without the main PyQt application running.  This means that crawler is reset every time the loop iterates and in the end it is just the crawler with the last url.

One solution might be to save the instances of the instantiated Crawlers

```
def main():
    app = QApplication( sys.argv )

    # Get all the urls
    with open(r'urls.txt','r') as urls:
        my_urls = [u.rstrip("\n") for u in urls]

    # Instantiate all the Crawlers
    crawlers = [Crawler(u, "output.txt") for u in my_urls]

    # Call all of the crawlers' crawl methdos
    for crawler in crawlers:
        crawler.crawl()

    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: Hmm didn't work for me.  I got an error in your main(), which I changed to: "with open(r'urls.txt','r') as urls:urls = [u.replace("\n","") for u in urls]".  After that the program runs without error but does not fully load either webpage.  Instead of getting the full html, I get "<html><head></head><body></body></html>"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error!  Are you sure the urls you are looking at have a body? Did you check them in a browser or `curl` them?

Comment: Would it be possible to post some of the URLs that are in urls.txt?

Comment: I'm just testing it on abc's homepage and espn's homepage which I can't type into this comment box for some reason but it's just http:// www. abc/espn .com.  When I run just one of those urls on the blogger's code I get the full html page.

Comment: Ahh good point! I've updated the solution with another possible fix.

Comment: Hmm not working for me, it's again just looping through all urls and then only returning the last one.